# Is it correct to use question mark after colon and quote?

Tags: punctuation

In this sentence how can I use the question mark and period correctly?

> When a person prepares a meal for me, after I finish my meal, why does
> this thought make me silent: "blah blah blah."?

Comment: Yes. I'd omit the period at the end of the quote though

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is correctly used in the example you've given. However, you should probably remove the period at the end of the "blah blah blah".